# expression pattern of type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>' cannot match values of type 'Int'?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

At one point before Swift 3 this code would work without any compile errors however after converting to Swift 3 this code isn't compiling and I don't completely understand how the value types are different.

The error given is `expression pattern of type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>' cannot match values of type 'Int'` for the switch cases where I'm attempting to use different ranges of values in the switch statement:

```
switch hour {
        case 0 ... 11:
            greetingStatement.text = "Good Morning"
        case 12 ... 24:
            greetingStatement.text = "Good Evening"
        default:
            greetingStatement.text = "Hello"
        }
```

Here is the full code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var userInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usertOutput: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var tapMeAfterEnteringYourName: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var greetingStatement: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var letsGetStartedLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var ballonsImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var teacherPointingToBoardImage: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func setOutput(_ sender: AnyObject){
        greetingStatement.isHidden = false
        usertOutput.text=userInput.text
        tapMeAfterEnteringYourName.isHidden = true
        userInput.isHidden = true
        letsGetStartedLabel.isHidden = false
        ballonsImageView.isHidden = false

        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.hour], from: date)
        let hour = components.hour
        switch hour {
        case 0 ... 11:
            greetingStatement.text = "Good Morning"
        case 12 ... 24:
            greetingStatement.text = "Good Evening"
        default:
            greetingStatement.text = "Hello"
        }
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
        teacherPointingToBoardImage.isHidden=true

        var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.4, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateViewController), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


        let hover = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        hover.isAdditive = true
        hover.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.zero)
        hover.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -100.0))
        hover.autoreverses = true
        hover.duration = 5
        hover.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        ballonsImageView.layer.add(hover, forKey: "myHoverAnimation")



    }

    func updateViewController() {

        print("Timer just fired")
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MadLibOneViewController") as! MadLibOneViewController
        self.present(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor=UIColor.purple
        usertOutput.textColor=UIColor.white
        userInput.textColor = UIColor.purple
        greetingStatement.isHidden = true
        letsGetStartedLabel.isHidden = true
        ballonsImageView.isHidden = true







    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

Can someone clarify that  is simply a generic where any type of Int is allowable or expected?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is misleading. The problem is that `hour` is an optional `Int`.

I would change the code to:

```
if let hour = components.hour {
    switch hour {
    case 0 ... 11:
        greetingStatement.text = "Good Morning"
    case 12 ... 24:
        greetingStatement.text = "Good Evening"
    default:
        greetingStatement.text = "Hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an example where you can safely forced unwrap the optional because one line above you explicitly got the `hour` component.

Comment: @vadian What do you mean? Where? What line? Keep in mind that `components.hour` returns `Int?`, not `Int`.

Comment: Yes, but there is always a value. `components([.hour]` from a valid date like `Date()` returns never `nil`.

Comment: @vadian Perhaps. But its type is `Int?` so safely unwrapping is prudent.

Comment: `Int("10")` is `Int?`, too. Can it ever be `nil`? The reason for the optional properties is the more convenient and shorter way to initialize `DateComponents` with default `nil` `don't care` values.

Comment: @vadian Maybe. I don't know. It might depend on the user's locale.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use the API to return a single non-optional value

```
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
switch hour { ...
```

By the way `components:from` has been renamed to `dateComponents:from` in Swift 3. That avoids the extra bridge cast.